# jQuery Animate Colors Issue (killing hover state)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Using :

```
$('#menu a').animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4)'})
```

In my document with jquery.animate-colors ... works fine but is killing the hover state of #menu a....

I've tried resetting it with

```
$("#menu a:hover").css("backgroundColor", "#ddd");
```

to no avail.

thoughts?

Comment: How about a jsFiddle so we can get the other 90% of the story?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UP8M6/

Answer (score 0):

The previously specified CSS `:hover` has been overruled by the jQuery styling. JS/jQuery put it's styling in an inline-type attribute `<div style=""></div>`, thus overriding the styles set in CSS. But these rules can be override as well by just placing the keyword `!important`.

```
#test:hover {background-color:#000 !important;}
```